# add var to a href in file where this var is loaded from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I want the var fam_id in the a href as a session var

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kinderen WHERE fam_id between $fammin and $fammax order by fam_id"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td><a href='kindtwee.php'>". $row["fam_id"] ." </a></td>
                <td>". $row["naam"] ."</td><td>". $row ["vnaam"] ."</td>
                <td>". $row ["pnaam"] ." </td>  
                <td>". $row ["pvnaam"] ."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear! Do you want to put `$row["fam_id"]` into a session var? Or do you want to use a session var instead of `$row["fam_id"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
"<tr><td><a href='kindtwee.php?session=$row[fam_id]'>". $row["fam_id"] ." </a></td>
```

You can access it with `$_REQUEST` variable. Although if you want it as sessionID why not store it in session variable which can be accessed on your website everywhere:

```
 $_SESSION['id'] = $fam_id;
```

Comment: what is the $fam_id here?

Comment: typo, just change it to one you want to be assigned to that session variable.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve you issue

```
"<tr><td><a href='kindtwee.php?session=$row[fam_id]'>". $row["fam_id"] ." </a></td>";
```

kindtwee.php:

```
 $fam_id="";
 if(isset($_REQUEST['session'])){
$fam_id=$_REQUEST['session'];
}

 $_SESSION['id'] = $fam_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It works wonderfull. 1 week I've lost chearching.